# k partition algorithm - divide work load equally between k workers

Tags: algorithm

I once read a problem in my Introduction to Algorithms (MIT Press) book which stated.

We have a book with 100 pages and each page has a weight associated with it equal to its page number therefore the weights are i.e. 1,2,3,4,5. These weights represent the difficulty of the page in translation to other language. We have K people assigned the work of translating the pages in another language but we have to divide the work load such that they have almost equal amount of work.

So if we have 5 pages i.e 1,2,3,4,5 and K=3 then k1=2+3=5, k2=1+4=5 and k3=5

Do you have online reference to this problem because I can't find it on google?
OR
Do you know the name of this algorithm?

Comment: Is that the book with the red mobile on the cover? I loved that book; glad to hear it's still being used.

Comment: @Ether: I haven't seen a red mobile on it, at least its not there on the cover of the book that I used :), may be there on a older version!

Comment: http://mitpress.mit.edu/algorithms/

Comment: I am sorry if I understood wrongly what you meant by mobile, is the thing on the cover called Mobile?, Thanks

Comment: Ahh .. Google helped me out :) .. "sculpture suspended in midair whose delicately balanced parts can be set in motion by air currents". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an instance of the first fit descending algorithm to me.

Answer (score 0):

That's known as First Fit Descending or First Fit Decreasing, or sometimes the bin packing algorithm, as it's used for efficiently packing objects into containers or for cutting pieces of a material into smaller components.

There's a nice implementation for Perl in the module [Algorithm::BinPack](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Algorithm::BinPack).

Comment: But what are the bin sizes in this context?  There isn't a limit to the amount of work a worker can do.

Comment: I guess you can just add each item to the bin with the smallest sum, but the first fit decreasing algorithm is still only an approximation algorithm, so it won't always return the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Special Case:** ***I Just thought this could be interesting***

Reminds me of the story of Gauss in elementary school...

No need for anything fancy, a translator will get two pages at a time,

```
1+100=101
2+99=101
...
50+51=101
```

So we split 50 pages between the translators (any order would do), they would also get the 101-x th page with the x page.

pseudo-code:

```
n=100 // 100 pages
k=5   // 5 translator
for i=1 to n/2
    print "Translator " ,(i mod k) +1, "gets pages", i , " and " , n-i+1
```

note: if n were odd, or if n/2 were not divisible by j, the work won't be fairly divided between the translators - this works perfectly in case n=100 and k in (1,2,5,10,25,50).

Comment: oh man. Whenever someone brought up a NP-Hard problem, my algorithms professor would always tell this story.